# rearranging input strings in aplhabetical order datastage

Tags: datastage

suppose my input is "Arun". I want the output as "Anru" that means strings should be rearranged in alphabetical order. The same task I have to perform on multiple input columns which has similar words. How an I acheive this in data stage.I tried by pivoting each input string and then performing column sort and pivoting back, but I don't think that is a healthy method.

Comment: Please add the relevant code parts you already tried.

Comment: So "Arun" is the content of a single column? In my eyes pivoting is the right idea unless you want to write some C- code for it and use it in a DataStage BuildOp.